# Object Collection

Tags: php, mysql, object

I'm making a class which needs to provide me with all the data from the MySQL-table "content".

I want to have my data returned as an object.
So far I managed to get one object returned, but i'd like to get an Object Collection with all my rows from the database returned.

```
<?
class ContentItem {
public $id;
public $title;
public $subtitle;
public $conent;
public $intro_length;
public $active;
public $start_date;
public $end_date;
public $views;

static function getContentItems() {     
    $query = "SELECT * FROM content";

    $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
    $item = new ContentItem(); 
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
          $item = $data;                            
    } 
    return $item;           
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop keeps overwriting `data` with `item`, and `new ContentItem()` is overwritten immediately.  If by "object collection" you mean "array," it's quite simple:

```
$items = array();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
   $items[] = $data;
}
return $items;
```

If you want to return your own custom object collection, then define the collection class and add $data to its collection each time (probably stored in an array as well).

Answer (score 5):

For collections you need to create an object which implements [Iterator interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php). You can fill it with arrays, objects or whatever you want. `Iterator` makes sure you can use this collection in `foreach` loops after.

Furthermore, there's a mistake in your code. You are overwriting `$item` over and over again. You should create an array (or object with implemented `Iterator`, as I mentioned) which will be filled each cycle of while (as [tandu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205767/object-collection/5205805#5205805) wrote already).

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be an array. I also assume you want a ContentItem made from each set of $data

```
$items = array();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
      $items[] = new ContentItem($data);
} 
return $items;
```

If you later want to work with the items, you can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // do something with $item
}
```